# Super-high resolution on my Acer chromebook 14

Tags: google-chrome, resolution

There is a display setting for a resolution of 2400*1350. And I am pretty sure that the spec for the display is full HD (1920*1080)

So My question is: is this the real hardware level resolution, or pseudo high resolution achieved by software level emulation? Maybe it is a new experimental feature added by Chrome OS (I am on a Dev release channel)?
[image: Setting to reach a higher than a full HD resoultion]

Comment: 1920 x 1080 looks like the native resolution of the screen.  The higher resolution would either be for an external monitor or some form of interpolated resolution that lets you reduce 2400 x 1350 source material to be displayed on the screen at reduced resolution, or perhaps as a 1920 x 1080 window onto a 2400 x 1350 virtual screen.

Comment: Thanks fixer1234, I think 2400X1350 is a interpolated resolution too. In that case, other chrome books, depending on Chrome OS version probably, will have a similar setting for a higher display resolution than the display panel's native resolution I assume.

Answer (score 0):

After using the 2400 x 1350 resolution for a little while, it is pretty clear that the higher resolution does display more content and behave like a higher resolution, but dose not provide more clarity compare to lower resolution such as full HD.

I conclude that the display panel has a hardware resolution of full HD, no more.

It is still interesting to know that Chrome OS provide ability to get a resolution higher than the actual capability of the hardware, which I don't think I've saw it on other OS!